# How Container end() iterator evolves when (e.g) Container size change

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I was wondering why the test below

> end_iter_mem == intList.end()

return true

[coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7afae1b4e0321bca)

Shouldn't the end() "value" of the container evolves when (among other) container's number of elements increases ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<int> intList = {1,2,3};

    auto end_iter_mem = intList.end();

    intList.push_back(4);

    cout << (end_iter_mem == intList.end()) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterators for lists are not invalidated after `list::push_back` operations, from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/push_back)

> No iterators or references are invalidated.

But this does not mean that this is true for all containers.  For example for [vectors the documentation says](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)

> If the new size() is greater than capacity() then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated. Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated.

---

tl;dr You have to consult the documentation to find out whether iterators are invalidated and which iterators are invalidated after a container modification.